# Using the unix sed command - sed 's/[\t]\+/,/g' - need without using 'comma'

Tags: unix, mysql, sed, csv

I am trying to export the query output into a `.csv` file. Please help as am a newbie to the SED world.

```
mysql -h <host> -u'uname' -p'pword' -e 'SELECT * from schema.table'  | sed 's/[\t]\+/,/g' > <path>table.csv;
```

When `sed 's/[\t]\+/,/g'` is used, fields with value having comma (`,`) move to the next column.

---

Current state, data has moved to column K:

[image: screenshot - data has moved to column K]

---

The desired state is like this:

[image: screenshot - how data should be displayed]

How to make it work?

Comment: Do you want to import data to a spreadsheet? or to create a proper csv file? Spreadsheet software may be able to properly import tsv (tab-separated) data and export it to csv (comma-separated), with *proper quoting* to preserve actual commas (and other troublesome characters in general). I guess this (not `sed`) is the way to go. What spreadsheet is in the first screenshot? What spreadsheet software can you use?

Comment: Thank you Kamil. I wanted the output in an excel format for the data comparison. Extracting it to .xls instead of csv and removed the SED functions solved my problem.